# Python (не работают модули)

Tags: python

Не работает модуль в python (pip тоже)

```
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mincss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mincss' is not defined
>>> import mincss
>>> mincss
<module 'mincss' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\mincss\\__init__.py'>
>>> mincss http://github.com
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    mincss http://github.com
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: А что конкретно вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Что такое по-вашему `mincss http://github.com` и что эта конструкция по-вашему вообще должна делать?

Comment: REPL выводит вам какие-то сообщения... Я думаю, это неспроста..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы бездумно скопировали строчку из документации и даже не удосужились разобраться, что же там написано.

А написана там команда для терминала. Вместе с модулем mincss устанавливается команда mincss (куда устанавливается — зависит от вашей операционной системы), и надо не в питоне к модулю обращаться, а запускать эту самую команду в обыкновенном терминале.

Если вы не знаете, куда установилась команда `mincss` и как её запустить — спросите это в отдельном вопросе, указав там способ, которым вы установили mincss, а также версию Python и вашей операционной системы.

[image: скриншот из линуксов]

Comment: Будьте любезны. поясните за `mincss github.com`? Что оно делает с гитхаб?

Comment: @vp_arth минифицирует его CSS, не?)

Comment: css гитхаба? главной страницы гитхаба? рекурсивный поиск?

Comment: @vp_arth а вот фиг знает, я в документации про эту команду вообще ни слова не нашёл (кроме собственно строчки `$ mincss https://github.com`)